# Удаление атрибута disabled. Jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Добрый вечер!Не могу понять,в чем проблема, кнопка как была неактивной,так и остается недоступной для нажатия.
Более понятней будет,взглянув на изображение:

[image: Картинка]

Где в Sass

```
.selected
  border: 1px solid red

.selectedgood
  border: 1px solid green
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#boughtamount").keyup(function() {
  var value = this.value;
  var price = 0;
  if (value > 100 && value < 100000) {
    price = parseInt(value) * 1.25;
    $("#boughtamount").addClass("selectedgood");
    $('.res_sum').text(price);
  } else{
    $("#boughtamount").addClass("selected"); 
    $("#boughtamount").removeClass("selectedgood");  
      }
    if (this.value != this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '')) 
    { this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
    }  
   });
  $("#useremail").keyup(function() {
    if($(this).val() != '') {
      var pattern = /^([a-z0-9_\.-])+@[a-z0-9-]+\.([a-z]{2,4}\.)?[a-z]{2,4}$/i;
        if(pattern.test($(this).val())){
          $("#useremail").addClass("selectedgood");
        } else{
           $("#useremail").addClass("selected"); 
           $("#useremail").removeClass("selectedgood");
        } 

    }
  });
  $("#charname").keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val() != '' && $(this).val().length > 3 ) {
      $("#charname").addClass("selectedgood");
    } else {
      $("#charname").removeClass("selectedgood");
      $("#charname").addClass("selected");
    }
  });


});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#addtobacket").keyup(function() {
    if ( $("#useremail").hasClass("selectedgood") && $("#boughtamount").hasClass("selectedgood") && $("#charname").hasClass("selectedgood")){
        $("#addtobacket").removeAttr('disabled');
    } else{
        $("#addtobacket").attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
      }); 
  });
```

html

```
<div class="buttons">
                        <div class="buttonbacket">
                            <input type="button" value="Добавить в корзину" id="addtobacket" disabled="disabled">
                        </div>
                        <div class="quick">
                            <input type="button" value="Купить в один клик" id="buyfast" disabled="disabled">
                        </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот обработчик

```
$("#addtobacket").keyup(function() {
```

предназначен для кнопки? Если у нее изначально состояние `disabled`, какие `keyup`-ы она будет получать?

Вам надо переводить кнопку в активное/неактивное состояние в других обработчиках `keyup`. Напишите функцию:

```
function SetButtonState() {
  if ( $("#useremail").hasClass("selectedgood") &&
       $("#boughtamount").hasClass("selectedgood") &&
       $("#charname").hasClass("selectedgood")) {
    $("#addtobacket").removeAttr('disabled');
  } else{
    $("#addtobacket").attr('disabled','disabled');
  }
}
```

и вызывайте ее в конце каждого из `keyup`-обработчиков.

Comment: Один, нажал в sublime ctrl+F и через поиск addtobacket , ровно один элемент

Comment: Ой,верно... :( А на что заменить, попробовал .click(), тоже не работает  http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: @mex111 Не забывайте принимать ответы на Ваши вопросы - значок "галочка" слева от ответа.

Comment: спасибо большое